# Downloading websocket in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, websocket, augmented-reality

i fin that i should download ths package (websocketdsharp) but when i did the outpout was the same.

when i tried to compile this c# script in unity

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using WebSocketSharp;
using TMPro;
public class Temperature : MonoBehaviour
{
 [SerializeField]
 private TextMeshPro textMesh = null;
 WebSocket ws;
 string messageWs;
 private void Start()
 {
 ws = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.1.8:1880/ws/Temperature");
 ws.Connect();
 }
 void Update()
 {
 ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) => messageWs = e.Data;
 if (textMesh == null)
 {
 textMesh = GetComponent<TextMeshPro>();
 }
 if (textMesh != null)
 {
 textMesh.text = $"Temperetaure : " + messageWs ;
 }
 }
}
```

the outpout was like this:
Assets\Script\Temperature.cs(10,2): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'WebSocket' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In "Assets/Script" directory, is there any assembly definition file(.asmdef)? If there it is, you should make it refer the WebSocketSharp package's asmdef, or remove the asmdef file in your Script folder.